SQL Multi PIVOT Query
I have the following Data Structure in my Db which stores lots of different (dynamic) values based off a formsite import, I need to write a query which will return all possible combination of values so that I can use it in further data processing.
Table structure:



ID
CODE
VALUE




1
A
z


1
B
y


1
A
x


1
C
w


1
B
v


2
A
x


2
B
y



What I would like as an output is as follows:



Id
A
B
C




1
z
y
w


1
x
y
w


1
z
v
w


1
x
v
w


2
x
y




I have tried all types of Pivoting, RowNubers, Ranks but non seem to be giving me the exact output i need.
declare @table table (ID int, Code nvarchar(10), value nvarchar(30))


insert into @table(Id,Code,Value)
values
(1,N'A',N'z'),
(1,N'B',N'y'),
(1,N'A',N'x'),
(1,N'C',N'w'),
(1,N'B',N'v'),
(2,N'A',N'x'),
(2,N'B',N'y')

select * from @table

select 
    *
into #r1
from (
    select 
        row_number() over(partition by id order by code) as RowNumberColumn ,
        id,
        code,
        value 
    from @table

) as t
pivot (
    max(value) for code in (A,B,C)
) as p
select * from #r1

select 
    * 
from #r1 as p
join #r1 as c on p.ID = c.ID and p.RowNumberColumn <> c.ID


select 
    * 
from #r1 as p
join #r1 as c on p.ID = c.ID and p.RowNumberColumn <> c.ID

select distinct 
    p.Id,
    p.RowNumberColumn,
    coalesce(c.a,p.a) as A,
    coalesce(c.b,p.b) as B,
    coalesce(c.c,p.c) as C
from #r1 as p, #r1 as c 
where p.ID = c.ID
    and (p.a <> c.a
    or p.b <> c.b
    or p.c <> c.c
    )


drop table #r1

Can anyone help me understand what piece I am missing.
EDIT: there will be multiple Codes which can have multiple values associated to an ID. So hard coding a number of joins is not an option

Well, If the number/values of the "Code" column are varied, then a PIVOT won't work for you anyways, since you have to define them ahead of time.  Leaving you with dynamic SQL for a solution, so if you can work out a solution with JOIN's, then go that route and make it dynamic.

The simplest variation of the query you want that I can think of would look like this if you were to hard-code it (and assuming this will actually run against a real or #temp table, not a @table variable):
  SELECT ID = COALESCE(c1.Id, c2.Id, c3.Id),
          A = COALESCE(c1.value, ''),
          B = COALESCE(c2.value, ''),
          C = COALESCE(c3.value, '')
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT Id, value FROM #table WHERE Code = 'A'
    ) AS c1
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT Id, value FROM #table WHERE Code = 'B'
    ) AS c2 
    ON c1.Id = c2.Id
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT Id, value FROM #table WHERE Code = 'C'
    ) AS c3
    ON c2.Id = c3.Id
    ORDER BY ID;

But you can't do that if you don't know the names of the codes or how many there could be. So, let's use dynamic SQL, assuming SQL Server 2017 or better (or an Azure flavor). It will be ugly to read, but manually maintaining a hard-coded version every time you get a new Code will be a lot uglier.
DECLARE @SQLCommand nvarchar(max),
        @KeyColumns nvarchar(max),
        @SelectList nvarchar(max),
        @JoinTables nvarchar(max),
        @crlf char(2) = char(13) + char(10),
        @apos char(1) = char(39);
  
;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT Code, codecount = COUNT(*) OVER(),
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Code)
  FROM #table GROUP BY Code
)
SELECT @KeyColumns = N'ID  = COALESCE(' + (SELECT 
         STRING_AGG(CONCAT(N'c', rn, N'.Id'), N',') FROM src) + N'),',
       @SelectList = (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(QUOTENAME(Code), 
         N' = COALESCE(c', rn, N'.value, N'''')'), 
         N',' + char(10)) FROM src),
       @JoinTables = (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
         CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN N' FROM ' + @crlf END,
         N'(SELECT Id, value FROM #table WHERE Code = N''', 
         REPLACE(Code, @apos, @apos + @apos), N''')', 
         @crlf, N' AS c', rn, CASE 
         WHEN rn > 1 THEN CONCAT(N' ON c', rn - 1, 
         N'.Id = c', rn, N'.Id') END, CASE 
         WHEN rn < codecount THEN @crlf + N' FULL OUTER JOIN ' END), 
         char(10)) FROM src);

SET @SQLCommand = CONCAT_WS(@crlf, N'SELECT ', 
   @KeyColumns, @SelectList, @JoinTables, N'ORDER BY Id;');

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQLCommand; 

Produces, in this case, something identical syntax-wise, and pretty darned close formatting-wise:
SELECT 
ID  = COALESCE(c1.Id,c2.Id,c3.Id),
[A] = COALESCE(c1.value, N''),
[B] = COALESCE(c2.value, N''),
[C] = COALESCE(c3.value, N'')
 FROM 
(SELECT Id, value FROM #table WHERE Code = N'A')
 AS c1
 FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT Id, value FROM #table WHERE Code = N'B')
 AS c2 ON c1.Id = c2.Id
 FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT Id, value FROM #table WHERE Code = N'C')
 AS c3 ON c2.Id = c3.Id
ORDER BY Id;


db<>fiddle example
and another example that is easier to read there but would make for lots of scrolling here.

